# semicircle arclength comparison

Tags: geometry

[image]
How semicircle with arc-length $6 \pi$  could be drawn in the option 1 whereas the radius has $4\pi$ arclength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arc length of a circle is $2\pi r$, so the radius need only be $3\lt r\lt 7$ so that the arc length is $\theta r=6\pi\lt 14\pi$.

If a "semicircle" is taken as "half a circle", then the inequality is $6=r\lt 7$, and still applies.